# What is the Response.Redirect equivalent in Silverlight 5?

Tags: silverlight

How to go another page in Mysilverlight project. What is the response.redirect in silverlight?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`NavigationService.Navigate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationService(v=vs.95).aspx) to load another page:

```
public partial class Page1 : Page
{
    public Page1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Loaded += Page1_Loaded;
    }

    private void Page1_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("SomeUserControl.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
    }
}
```

Note that the "NavigationService" is a member of the `Page` class.  [You can only navigate from within the context of a page or frame](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/180658/Navigation-Framework-in-Silverlight-4.aspx) -- you can't navigate from within the application itself.